# Is it possible to to use apply with different vectors to each column?

Tags: r, apply

Apologies to the poor question title.  Not too sure how to describe the problem here.
First, I have the code below.

```
# Data
set.seed(100)
x = matrix(runif(10000,0,1),100,100)
grpA = round(runif(100,1,5),0) # Group 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

# function
funA <-function(y, A){
  X = lm(y~A)
  return(X$residuals)
}

# Calculation  
A = apply(x,1,function(y) funA(y,grpA))
```

Now, instead of having grpA, I have grpB below which the groups are different for every column. Besides looping each column, can I still use the apply to calculate this?  If so, how?
My actual funA calcultion is a lot more complex and I do need to calculate funA many times so I am trying to aviod using the for loop.  Thanks.

```
grpB = matrix(round(runif(10000,1,5),0),100,100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an answer to

> can I still use the apply to calculate this?  If so, how?

The answer is yes. You can combine `x` and `grpB` into an `array` and then use apply on the resulting array.

```
# Data
set.seed(100)
x = matrix(runif(10000,0,1),100,100)
grpA = round(runif(100,1,5),0) # Group 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
# function
funA <-function(y, A){
  X = lm(y~A)
  return(X$residuals)
}
# Original calculation  
A <- apply(x, 1, funA, grpA)
# the array in this case
arr <- array(c(x, matrix(rep(grpA, 100), nrow=100, byrow=TRUE)), dim=c(nrow(x), ncol(x), 2))
# the new calculation 
res <- apply(arr, 1, function(y) funA(y[, 1], y[, 2]))
# comparing results
all.equal(A, res)
## TRUE
# 
# and for the new groupB
grpB = matrix(round(runif(10000,1,5),0),100,100)
# the array
arr <- array(c(x, grpB), dim=c(nrow(x), ncol(x), 2))
# the calculation (same as above)
res <- apply(arr, 1, function(y) funA(y[, 1], y[, 2]))
```

See @mrip's answer for  the reasons this may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

First off, if your function `funA` does a lot of work, then using a `for` loop versus `apply` won't affect performance that much.  This is because the only difference is in the overhead of looping, and most of the work is going to take place inside of `funA` in either case.

In fact, even if `funA` is simple, `for` and `apply` won't be that different performance-wise.  Either way, there needs to be a loop inside of R with multiple R function calls.  The real performance improvements by avoiding `for` loops come in situations where there is a builtin R function that performs the computation you need by looping in the underlying C code without the overhead of multiple function calls in R.  Here is an illustrative example.

```
x<-matrix(runif(10000,0,1),100,100)
require(microbenchmark)
f1<-function(z){
  ret<-rep(0,ncol(z))
  for(i in 1:ncol(z)){
      ret[i]<-sum(z[,i])
  }
  ret
}
f2<-function(z){
  apply(z,2,sum)
}
identical(f1(x),f2(x))
# [1] TRUE
identical(f1(x),colSums(x))
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark(f1(x),f2(x),colSums(x))
# unit: microseconds
#       expr     min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#       f1(x) 559.934 581.4775 596.4645 622.1425  773.519   100
#       f2(x) 484.265 512.1570 526.5700 546.5010 1100.540   100
#  colSums(x)  23.844  25.7915  27.0675  28.7575   59.485   100
```

So, in your situation, I wouldn't worry about using a `for` loop.  There are ways to avoid a loop, for example, something like

```
sapply(1:ncol(x),function(i) fun(x[,i],y[,i]))
```

But it won't be much faster than a for loop.

Comment: Exactly. One could use `lm(t(x) ~ groupA)` instead, avoiding the loop at the R level. Or use `lm.fit` if a loop is required. Lessons: Avoid R loops if possible. If not optimize the code inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use a `sequence` of the number of columns as an "indicator" or "extracting" variable, and use `vapply` instead of `apply`, like this:

```
vapply(sequence(ncol(x)), 
       function(z) funA(x[, z], grpB[, z]), 
       numeric(nrow(x)))
```